# Using RABL templates with server-side handlebars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, rabl

We use handlebars (with sht_rails) in a Rails project for both client- and server-side templating. To feed client side templates we use RABL templates that provide JSON data. We'd like to use the same templates with same data on the server side, but server-side templates require hashes not JSON strings.

As a temporary solution we use `render_to_string` to generate JSON data and then `JSON.parse` to get a hash, but it seems to be ugly... Is there any better method to render a hash using RABL template?

I've tried [the solution described on github](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/321), but without success. We use`object false` in out templates so I don't know what to pass to the `Rabl::Renderer#new`. Additionally we use some RoR-specific methods (like `root_url`) and they seem to fail.